# Time since epoch is -1

Tags: c++, epoch, ctime

I am trying to get the number of seconds that have elapsed since epoch. The code:

```
long parseTime(string time) {

  cout << "Time entered = " << time << endl;

  long timeSinceEpoch;

  //takes in time in string format - date + time and returns seconds from epoch.
  /* Steps:
   * 1. Remove trailing and leading spaces.
   * 2. Check format of date.
   * 3. Convert to epoch.
   */

  //remove trailing and leading spaces.
  /*
  unsigned int leading = 0, trailing = 0;
  string whitespace = " \t";

  leading = time.find_first_not_of(whitespace);
  trailing = time.find_last_not_of(whitespace);

  string newTime = time.substr(leading, (trailing - leading + 1));
  cout << "Old time = " << time << " new time = " << newTime << endl;
  */
  string newTime = time;

  struct tm t;

  if(newTime.find("/") != string::npos) {
    //format of date is mm/dd/yyyy. followed by clock in hh:mm (24 hour clock).
    cout << "Time format contains slashes." << endl;
    if(strptime(newTime.c_str(), "%m/%e/%Y %H:%M", &t) == NULL) {
      cout << "Error. Check string for formatting." << endl;
    }
  } else if(newTime.find("-") != string::npos) {
    //format of date is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss (hh in 24 hour clock format).
    if(strptime(newTime.c_str(), "%Y-%m-%e %H:%M:%S", &t) == NULL) {
     cout << "Error. Check string for formatting of new date." << endl;
    }
  }

  if(t.tm_isdst) {
    t.tm_isdst = 0;
  }

  timeSinceEpoch = mktime(&t);
  cout << "Time since epoch = " << timeSinceEpoch << endl;

  return timeSinceEpoch;
}
```

Now, when a string containing date and time is passed to the function:
`3/26/2013 3:17`
It results in  time since epoch = -1. Here is the output from the debugger:

```
Breakpoint 2, parseTime (time=...) at informationExtractor.cpp:44
44        cout << "Time entered = " << time << endl;
(gdb) n
Time entered = 3/26/2013 3:17
66        string newTime = time;
(gdb)
70        if(newTime.find("/") != string::npos) {
(gdb) p newTime
$3 = {static npos = <optimized out>,
  _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>},
    _M_p = 0x8004ab0c "3/26/2013 3:17"}}
(gdb) n
72          cout << "Time format contains slashes." << endl;
(gdb)
Time format contains slashes.
73          if(strptime(newTime.c_str(), "%m/%e/%Y %H:%M", &t) == NULL) {
(gdb)
83        if(t.tm_isdst) {
(gdb) p newTime.c_str()@strlen(newTime.c_str())
Only values in memory can be extended with '@'.
(gdb) n
84          t.tm_isdst = 0;
(gdb) p newTime
$4 = {static npos = <optimized out>,
  _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>},
    _M_p = 0x8004ab0c "3/26/2013 3:17"}}
(gdb) n
87        timeSinceEpoch = mktime(&t);
(gdb) p t
$5 = {tm_sec = 1628993312, tm_min = 17, tm_hour = 3, tm_mday = 26, tm_mon = 2, tm_year = 113, tm_wday = 2, tm_yday = 84,
  tm_isdst = 0}
(gdb) n
88        cout << "Time since epoch = " << timeSinceEpoch << endl;
(gdb)
Time since epoch = -1
90        return timeSinceEpoch;
(gdb)
```

If you notice, `tm_sec` in `t` is 1628993312 while `timesinceEpoch` is -1. `tm_sec` is also well within the range for `long` which is the datatype of `timesinceEpoch`. Any ideas on why and how to solve for this are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that in your code tm_sec is an uninitialised value. It should be a value between 0 and 59. So add this line of code to your first if branch.

```
if(strptime(newTime.c_str(), "%m/%e/%Y %H:%M", &t) == NULL) {
  cout << "Error. Check string for formatting." << endl;
}
t.tm_sec = 0; // initialise seconds field
```

Comment: `tm_sec` set to 0 after it has been initialized with `strptime`? how would that work? also, the debugger output shows that `tm_sec` (time since epoch) is initialized to 1628993312 before being set to -1 after calling mktime.

Comment: My point is that it isn't being initialised by strptime, there's no %S in your format string.

Comment: im not sure i have understood this. the `%S` is for seconds and the time string input to the function does not have seconds, only hours:minutes.

Comment: That's fine, but **because** of those facts the tm_sec field in the tm struct is not getting set when you have slashes in your date. But mktime needs all the fields in the tm struct to be set. So in this case you have to set it manually.

Answer (score 1):

john is right.
`strptime` does not initialize `tm` and only touch fields which is explicitly specified ([see "**Notes**" of strptime(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime)),
so `t.tm_sec` is not initialized.

To prevent this kind of error, you can declare varialbes with initialization

```
struct tm t = { 0 }; // zero filled
```